# Formula to find the value after taking the square root of a number $n$ times?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I find the value after taking the square root of a number $n$ times?

For example:
$\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}$, $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}}$, $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}}}$ and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An expression for the number obtained by taking the square root of $a$ a total of $n$ times is $a^{1/2^n}$.

For $\sqrt{a}=a^{1/2}$, and $\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}=(a^{1/2})^{1/2}=a^{1/4}$, and $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{a}}} =(a^{1/4})^{1/2}=a^{1/8}$, and so on.

Comment: You are welcome.